# Erro 500 mais específico

Tags: php

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação WEB em PHP.

O problema que estou enfrentando, é que a aplicação está funcionando 100% localmente, porém quando jogo no servidor algumas coisas apresentam o erro 500. 
Mas o erro 500 é muito abstrato, acabo ficando perdido, olho o código e tá tudo certo.

Existe alguma forma de eu exibir mais especificamente qual erro está ocorrendo?

Console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: eu poderia debugar com o var_dump e console.log ou algo assim, o problema é que quando subo o site ele leva pelo menos 15min para completar o deploy.

OBS²: Utilizo servidor AWS (Amazon Web Services)

Comment: Um dos primeiros hábitos que quem mexe com PHP deve criar, no meu ver, é estar sempre de olho no log de erros.

Comment: Você pode ir na aba network e verificar se tem mais detalhes sobre o erro selecionando a requisição que resultou em falha

Comment: @JrD considerando que a aba network funciona do lado do cliente e o erro 500 ocorre do lado do servidor, acho improvável que vá encontrar muitos detalhes no caso específico. (mas não vejo mal nenhum em olhar lá, obviamente)

Comment: @JrD erro 500 indica um erro generico ocorrido na aplicação em back-end, ali no console já aparece a página do erro, no entanto Otavio, o problema pode ser a versão do seu PHP que é diferente do servidor e o seu PHP pode estar escrito de forma que não é compativel com a sua hospedagem. Outra possibilidade é que esqueceu de configurar algo, como banco. Mas só com isto de informação é impossivel lhe ajudar no momento.

Comment: @Bacco vou dar uma pesquisada nesse log ai, valeu!

Comment: @JrD na verdade eu já olhei o network, ele não tem nenhuma informação sobre o erro.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento 
A versão acredito estar correta, pois a aplicação já esta pronta e no ar a um tempo, eu apenas altero e subo, não fui eu quem desenvolveu. 
De qualquer forma, vou dar uma olhada, obrigado!

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha talvez algo que adicionou, talvez algo que mudou a sintaxe, talvez algum include, talvez o modo que fez o upload via FTP (sim, isso pode truncar os arquigos), pode ser inumeras coisas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, erro 500 é amplo demais, exatamente esse meu problema, preciso ver mais especificamente o que está ocorrendo, vou tentar achar o log pra ver se consigo ver

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Olá, sempre passo por isso e normalmente resolvo assim:

Criando uma versão assíncrona e pedindo para o PHP mostrar os erros:

```
#início do arquivo
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/erro.log"); // não sei ao certo se isso corrige o delay que você disse ter
```

para tentar deixar prático essa URL assíncrona, talvez isso ajude:

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        500: function() {
        console.log(versao-assincrona.php?var1&var2...);
        }
      }
   });
```

isso me dá velocidade, pois aparece o erro 500 e já testo a URL assíncrona em outra aba com o php exibindo os erros.

Eu resolvo assim, mas pode ter formas melhores.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Valeu cara, vou testar aqui e se funcionar aceito sua resposta

Comment: Você merece um beijo na boca!

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger XD