# Requisição Ajax com Error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Galera, boa tarde !

Estou montando um gerenciador de local, e estou com problema na consulta dos campos obrigatórios, está retornando Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

jquery.js:9664 POST http://localhost/project/restrict/ajax_save_locais 500 (Internal Server Error)

segue meu código:

**Formulário:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Local</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input id="local_name" name="local_name" class="form-control" maxlength="100">
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Imagem</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <img id="local_img_path" src="" style="max-height: 400px; max-width: 400px;">
                        <label class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Importar imagem
                            <input type="file" id="btn_upload_local_img" style="display: none;" accept="image/*">
                        </label>
                        <input id="local_img" name="local_img">
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**function is_duplicated:**

```
    public function is_duplicated($field, $value, $id = NULL) {
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $this->db->where("locais_id <>", $id);
    }
    $this->db->from("locais");
    $this->db->where($field, $value);
    return  $this->db->get()->num_rows() > 0;
}
```

**function ajax_save_locais:**

```
public function ajax_save_locais() {


    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        exit("Nenhum acesso de script direto permitido!");
    }

    $json = array();
    $json["status"] = 1;
    $json["error_list"] = array();

    $this->load->model("local_model");

    $data = $this->input->post();

    if (empty($data["local_name"])) {
        $json["error_list"]["#local_name"] = "Nome do local é obrigatório!";
    } else {
        if ($this->local_model->is_duplicated("local_name", $data["local_name"], $data["locais_id"])) {
            $json["error_list"]["#local_name"] = "Nome do local já existente!";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($json["error_list"])) {
        $json["status"] = 0;
    } else {

        if (!empty($data["local_img"])) {

            $file_name = basename($data["local_img"]);
            $old_path = getcwd() . "/tmp/" . $file_name;
            $new_path = getcwd() . "/public/images/locais/" . $file_name;
            rename($old_path, $new_path);

            $data["local_img"] = "/public/images/locais/" . $file_name;
        }

        if (empty($data["locais_id"])) {
            $this->local_model->insert($data);
        } else {
            $locais_id = $data["locais_id"];
            unset($data["locais_id"]);
            $this->local_model->update($locais_id, $data);
        }
    }
echo json_encode($json);
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function showErrorsModal(error_list) {
clearErrors();

$.each(error_list, function(id, message) {
    $(id).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
    $(id).siblings(".help-block").html(message)
})
```

}

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: BASE_URL + "restrict/ajax_save_locais",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $(this).serialize(),  
            beforeSend: function() {
                clearErrors();
                $("#btn_save_locais").siblings(".help-block").html(loadingImg("Verificando..."));
            },
            success: function(response) {
                clearErrors();
                if (response["status"]) {
                    $("#modal_locais").modal("hide");
                } else {
                    showErrorsModal(response["error_list"])
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá @João Lima, tudo bem?!

Olhando para o código, aparentemente está tudo normal. O ideal seria você utilizar um bloco `try` e `catch` para realizar a manipulação das exceções.

Você pode também adicionar o parâmetro error na sua configuração do ajax para manipular essa exceção no front-end. Exemplo:

```
try {
    if (empty($data["locais_id"])) {
        $this->local_model->insert($data);
    } else {
        $locais_id = $data["locais_id"];
        unset($data["locais_id"]);
        $this->local_model->update($locais_id, $data);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    die($errorMessage);
}
```

E você pode manipular essa exceção com o ajax:

```
success: function(response) {
    clearErrors();
    if (response["status"]) {
        $("#modal_locais").modal("hide");
    } else {
        showErrorsModal(response["error_list"])
    }
},
error: function (error) {
    console.log(error.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ei, Beleza João?

O Erro 500 (Internal Server Error), é um tipo de *status http* que o webservice (Apache/Nginx ou IIS) retorna quando ele **não consegue especificar o erro real** que ocorre internamente durante o acesso ao site, ou, no seu caso, a resposta do servidor.

Ele pode ocorrer por alguns motivos específicos, tais como:

Definição de parâmetros de forma incorreta através de um arquivo .htaccess;
Elevado uso de recursos ou timeout;
Permissões de arquivos incorretas (Linux);
Alto número de acessos simultâneos no site;
Erros de regravação de URL e de diretivas PHP.

Eu sugiro que verifique as rotas.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, eu já respondi algo parecido, esse é o link e a resposta abaixo, espero que ajude: [Erro 500 mais específico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368696/erro-500-mais-espec%C3%ADfico/368774#368774)

Criando uma versão assíncrona e pedindo para o PHP mostrar os erros:

```
#início do arquivo
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/erro.log");
```

// não sei ao certo se isso corrige o delay que você disse ter
para tentar deixar prático essa URL assíncrona, talvez isso ajude:

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        500: function() {
        console.log(versao-assincrona.php?var1&var2...);
        }
      }
   });
```

isso me dá velocidade, pois aparece o erro 500 e já testo a URL assíncrona em outra aba com o php exibindo os erros.

Eu resolvo assim, mas pode ter formas melhores.

Espero ter ajudado